# silverlight mouse position c#

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is there a way to get mouse position without attaching a event handler?

I'm trying to get a box to appear where the mouse is.

Thanks
Sp

Comment: You can use the mousemove event.

Comment: without attaching event? why?

Comment: It's very rare that I would use it so I thought that using and eventhandler would be a waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you rather want it on a mouse-up or mouse-down event? Here are a few drag-and-drop tutorials that might help with ideas for capturing mouse positions:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189066%28vs.95%29.aspx
- (SL 1, but still good) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickkramer/archive/2007/06/27/drag-drop-with-feedback.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you'll have no other way than using the MouseMove event. You can attach it to the `Application.Current.RootVisual` (or any other layout root) though, so you should be able to implement your scenario.